The principle by which Sentry stores files in self-hosted s3
As a part of the project, it became necessary to delete releases, as well as clear artifacts associated with them from the database(self-hosted s3).
However, there is a feeling that the files are not ultimately deleted, although they are not visible in the UI.
The maximum that I can see is that files are stored to the database using the following mask:
s3://bucketname/{ff}/{ffff}/{ffffffffffffffffffffffffff}

That is, the question is the following: how can I correlate the path in s3 with the file name (or its hash) to check that it was definitely deleted
